# Maxima solve returns no solutions

Tags: maxima

I defined a function like this:

```
f(x):=(4*x^4+7*x^3+(-3)*x)/(2*x^2+5)
```

And then assign the derivative to df like this:

```
df(x):=''(diff(f(x), x))
```

Maxima then prints this as the calculated derivative:

```
df(x):=(16*x^3+21*x^2-3)/(2*x^2+5)-(4*x*(4*x^4+7*x^3-3*x))/(2*x^2+5)^2
```

Then I try to solve the derivative for df(x)=0 to find stationary points of f:

```
solve(df(x)=0, x);
```

But instead of solutions, Maxima gives me this:

```
[0=16*x^5+14*x^4+80*x^3+111*x^2-15]
```

Which suggests that there are no solutions. But if I plot the function df, it crosses the x-axis 3 times. So clearly there are 3 points where df(x)=0. Why can't Maxima find them? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df(x)` is a quintic (i.e., degree 5) polynomial, and as such it probably does not have a solution in terms of radicals. There are solvable quintics, although I suspect Maxima cannot determine whether a quintic is solvable or not. For more about the general theory about quintics, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Finding_roots_of_a_quintic_equation .

I think a workable approach is to look for numerical approximations. Take a look at the Maxima functions `realroots` and `allroots`.